# Problems with targeting my VS2010 to .NET4 Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I keep getting the following messages about frameworks in VS2010. Also I can no longer add .net 4 as a target framework. I have tried installing / repairing the .net 4 framework. It keeps telling me all is okay but then I still get the message and cannot target the .net 4 or add it from the drop down list in the project properties. I'm at a loss for what to do. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
Warning 8   The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

Comment: What frameworks do you see when you create a new project?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried downloading and installing this?:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8279

It has worked for other people.

As far as I am aware this is different than the .NET framework, which is just for running the apps.

Comment: This worked for me, but I first had to uninstall the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributables in order for the SDK install to work.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files[ (x86)]\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0

This is the folder VS looks for reference assemblies. Does it contain the correct things on your machine? If not, you need to repair VS.

This folder is not part of .NET 4 installation, so that's why repair .NET 4 does not help you much.